# Blow up does not commute with base change in general, Vakil's ex 24.2 P

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If $\pi:X \rightarrow Y$ is a flat morphism, and $Z$ is a closed subscheme of $Y$, then we could construct the blow up $\text{Bl}_Z Y$. Since $\pi$ is flat, the pullback of $\text{Bl}_Z Y$, i.e. $\text{Bl}_Z Y \times_Y X$ is isomrphic to $\text{Bl}_{Z \times_Y X} X$, and this is just the part (a) of ex 24.2 P, which I know how to prove.
\begin{array}{c}
Z \times_Y X & \rightarrow & Z  \\
\downarrow & & \downarrow \\
X & \rightarrow & Y \\
\end{array}

\begin{array}{ccc}
\text{Bl}_Z Y \times_Y X \cong \text{Bl}_{Z \times_Y X} X & \rightarrow & \text{Bl}_Z Y  \\
\downarrow & & \downarrow \\
X & \rightarrow & Y \\
\end{array}
Part (b) is to find an example to show that this is not true generally if $\pi$ is not flat, any one knows an example?

Comment: This has been answered as a comment by Ariyan Javanpeykar [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1691068/116766#comment3451678_1691101), for example.

Comment: Thank you, that is a good example